# How check if sms/inbox is empty?

Tags: android, sms, inbox

I'd like to know if we can write a short boolean test which return true if sms/inbox is empty or not.

Something like `Databse("content://sms/inbox")==null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
// Retrieve a Cursor pointing to the sms list and the size of it.
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor cur = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);
boolean ret = cur.getCount() > 0;
```

Remember to close the cursor afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900294/android-1-5-reading-sms-messages) , its not a simple one liner but it will give you the data you require. It seems there is no documented way to do this easily , you are going to have to do alot of manual work or hope someone has written a lib to do it all for you