# How to listen/subscribe to Outgoing SMS notifications?

Tags: android, sms

I just started a project that wants to listen to all `incoming / outgoing SMS` events and send the content of SMS to a WebServer.

I can easily register to all incoming SMS alert. However I can't find any way to register to outgoing SMS events.

Can someone please provide me some hint of how to do this?

Comment: Give a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900294/android-1-5-reading-sms-messages and http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android%2Bsms