# How to detect outgoing SMS messages in the backgound of an Android application?

Tags: android, sms, detection

How can I run an Android application in the background that counts the number of SMS messages sent and, in addition, determine the detail of each one?

Answer (score 2):

you can fetch sent msg:

```
    Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
    Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(mSmsinboxQueryUri,
                new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date",
                                "body", "type" }, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor1);
    String[] columns = new String[] { "address", "person", "date", "body","type" };
    if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
        String count = Integer.toString(cursor1.getCount());
        Log.e("Count",count);
        while (cursor1.moveToNext()){
            String address = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
            String name = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
            String date = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
            String msg = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
            String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[4]));
        }
    }
```

you can use counter to retrive recently sent sms.

See other useful links:

[Android: Is there any way to listen outgoing sms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787894/android-is-there-any-way-to-listen-outgoing-sms)

[Listen outgoing SMS or sent box in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808577/android-listen-outgoing-sms-or-sent-box)

[How to listen/subscribe to Outgoing SMS notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954464/how-to-listen-subscribe-to-outgoing-sms-notifications)

Comment: For some reason content://sms/sent doesn't work for me but content://sms/ does.  Why do you think this is the case?