# Phone open 6th sms on installing application

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application named AutoSms.I wan that when i open the application it should automatically open the 6th sms in the inbox.Can anybody tell me.How should i pursue

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this question for info on how to read SMSs from the ContentProvider:
[Android 1.5: Reading SMS messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900294/android-1-5-reading-sms-messages)