# How to get the sent and received sms details programatically in Android phone

Tags: android, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android 1.5: Reading SMS messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900294/android-1-5-reading-sms-messages)

I need to get the sms details from Android phone, that is sent and received  messages and all messages that are stored in Android device. How can I get them programmatically. Please help me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question for details on how to use the SMS ContentProvider.
[Android 1.5: Reading SMS messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900294/android-1-5-reading-sms-messages)